# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta...
Estoy implementando un sistema para un proyecto escolar y funciona todo perfecto menos una parte para implementar asignaturas.
Me da este error:

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\siad\admin\inscripcion_Asignaturas.php on line 190

Este es el codigo:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['NombreUsuario'])) {
     if ($_SESSION["NivelUsuario"] == 1) {
            $user = $_SESSION['NombreUsuario'];
              $codigo = $_SESSION["Codigo"];

              $consulta=mysql_query("select Foto from usuarios where Codigo = $codigo");                  
                while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
                         $foto=$filas['Foto'];                           
                 }
        ?>
             <?php 
          $consulta1="select idCarrera, NombreCarrera from carreras";
          $carrera=mysql_query($consulta1);
          $consulta2="select idAsignatura, NombreAsignatura from asignaturas";
          $asignaturas=mysql_query($consulta2);


             $consulta=mysql_query("select Foto from estudiantes where idEstudiante = $codigo");                  
                while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
                         $foto=$filas['Foto'];                           
                 }

                 $consulta2 = mysql_query("select concat (NombresEstudiante, ' ', ApellidosEstudiante) as Estudiante from estudiantes where idEstudiante = $codigo"); 
                 while($filas2=mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)){
                         $estudiante=$filas2['Estudiante'];                           
                 }

        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>SIAD UNI</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/logoUNI.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1-10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/back-to-top.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="incripciones_asignaturas/myjava.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
           <?php
        include ('menuAdmin.php');
            ?>
       <br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-md-3"><img src="../imagenes/logoSIAD.png" width="80" height="80" class="img-responsive"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6">         

                <img src="../imagenes/baner.png" class="img-responsive">

             </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
              <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="<?php echo $foto ?>" width="50px" height="50px">
              <h5><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:green; text-align: left; "></i><b> &nbsp; Online:</b> <?php echo $user ?></h5>
               </div> 

            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="../index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="admin.php">Administrador</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Inscripciones</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Content Row -->
<?php //include('otros/menuAdministrador.php') ?>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Content Column -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            </div>
            <center><h4><b>Incripciones de Clases</b></h4></center>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                       <form id="formulario" class="form-group" action="recibir_inscripcion_asignaturas.php" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group"> <label for="carrera" class="col-md-3 control-label">Carrera:</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select class="form-control" id="carrera" name="carrera">
                       <option>---- Seleccione una Carrera -----</option>
                      <?php 
                          while($fila=mysql_fetch_row($carrera)){
                          echo "<option value='".$fila['0']."'>".$fila['1']."</option>";
                          }
                          ?>
                      </select>
                       </div>
                    </div> <br>

                       <div class="form-group"> <label for="carrera" class="col-md-3 control-label">Asignaturas:</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select class="form-control" id="asignaturas" name="asignaturas">
                        <option>---- Seleccione una Asignatura -----</option>
                      <?php 
                          while($fila=mysql_fetch_row($asignaturas)){
                          echo "<option value='".$fila['0']."'>".$fila['1']."</option>";
                          }
                          ?>
                      </select>
                       </div>
                    </div> <br>

                     <div class="form-group"> <label for="carrera" class="col-md-3 control-label">Codigo Estudiante:</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estudiante" required="true" placeholder="Escriba el Codigo del Estudiante">
                       </div>
                    </div> <br>

                      <div class="form-group"> <label for="carrera" class="col-md-3 control-label">Observaciones:</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="observaciones" required="true" placeholder="Escriba las observaciones necesarias">
                       </div>
                    </div> <br>



              <div style="margin-top: 10px"> <center><input type="submit" value="Inscribir Asignatura"  class="btn btn-success" /></center>    </div>         
             </div>         
            </form>
                  <br>
 <br>

 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-1"><h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Buscar:</h4></div>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                   <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
                   <input type="text" name="txtbuscar" id="txtbuscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribir el nombre del Estudiante">

                   </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="submit" id="nuevo-producto" class="btn btn-success" value="Buscar Inscripcion"> 
                      </form>
                   </div>
                <br>
  </div>

    <div class="registros" style="width:100%;" id="agrega-registros">
<?php
include('conexion.php');


$registro = mysql_query("SELECT inscripciones_asignaturas.idInscripcion as Codigo, carreras.NombreCarrera as Carrera, asignaturas.NombreAsignatura as Asignatura, concat(estudiantes.NombresEstudiante, ' ' ,estudiantes.ApellidosEstudiante) as Estudiantes,
inscripciones_asignaturas.fechaInscripcion as fecha, inscripciones_asignaturas.observaciones as observaciones 
FROM inscripciones_asignaturas INNER JOIN carreras ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idCarrera=carreras.idCarrera 
INNER JOIN asignaturas ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idAsignatura=asignaturas.idasignatura 
INNER JOIN estudiantes ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idEstudiante=estudiantes.idestudiante");

if (isset($_POST['txtbuscar'])){
      $registro=mysql_query("SELECT inscripciones_asignaturas.idInscripcion as Codigo, carreras.NombreCarrera as Carrera, asignaturas.NombreAsignatura as Asignatura, concat(estudiantes.NombresEstudiante, ' ' ,estudiantes.ApellidosEstudiante) as Estudiantes,
inscripciones_asignaturas.fechaInscripcion as fecha, inscripciones_asignaturas.observaciones as observaciones 
FROM inscripciones_asignaturas INNER JOIN carreras ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idCarrera=carreras.idCarrera 
INNER JOIN asignaturas ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idAsignatura=asignaturas.idasignatura 
INNER JOIN estudiantes ON inscripciones_asignaturas.idEstudiante=estudiantes.idestudiante
where estudiantes.NombresEstudiante like '%".$_POST['txtbuscar']."%'"); 
    }

       echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
          <tr>
                      <th width="5%">Codigo</th>  
                        <th width="15%">Carrera</th>        
                        <th width="20%">Asignatura</th>
                        <th width="10%">Estudiantes</th>  
                        <th width="10%">Fecha</th>        
                        <th width="40%">Observaciones</th>
            </tr>';
      if(mysql_num_rows($registro)>0){
       while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
          echo '<tr>
                              <td>'.$registro2['Codigo'].'</td>
                              <td>'.$registro2['Carrera'].'</td>
                              <td>'.$registro2['Asignatura'].'</td>
                              <td>'.$registro2['Estudiantes'].'</td>
                              <td>'.$registro2['fecha'].'</td>
                              <td>'.$registro2['observaciones'].'</td>
                       </tr>';
        }
      }else{
        echo '<tr>
              <td colspan="10">No se encontraron resultados</td>
            </tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
?>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left;">
            <center>
                <ul class="pagination" id="pagination"></ul>
            </center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
           <center>
           <h4 style="font-weight: bold;"> 
    <?php
include('conexion.php');
    $numeroRegistros = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inscripciones_asignaturas"));
    echo "Registros Totales: $numeroRegistros";
        ?>
        </h4>
          </center>
      </div>


    <!-- MODAL PARA EL REGISTRO-->

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Fin del Panel -->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <?php
    include('../includes/footer.php');
 ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
     }
     else{
        echo '<script> alert("No Tienes los permisos para acceder a esta pagina.");</script>';
         echo '<script> window.location="../login.php"; </script>';
     }
}else{
 echo '<script> window.location="../login.php"; </script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice, que se esta pasando un valor boleano en otras palabras, que no esta realizando la busqueda de la informacion, la forma adecuada de utilizar la funcion msyql_query es :

```
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla1", $enlace);
$número_filas = mysql_num_rows($resultado);
```

Donde $enlace es la conexion de la base de datos, en tu codigo no tiene la coneccion.

Ejemplo sacado del manual de php http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Hola, ya le agregué el enlace a la base de datos y sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Puedes probar con el ejemplo 1 que viene en este enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php, ahi utiliza la funcion mysql_error() para saber cual es el fallo, ya que creo que es un error de tu consulta en sql

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta a respondida, y di cual fue la solucion, asi si alguien mas esta en lo mismo, podra ayudarse, crea una nueva pregunta y sube la seccion de codigo, no todo el codigo como hiciste esta vez, lo mas probable, es que tienes un error de sintaxis de php, te esta faltando un ";" o un "?>".

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, fue que tenía un } demás en un else

Comment: Ahora tengo un nuevo problema en otro formulario, el error es este:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$codigo' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\siad\estudiantes\inscripcion_asignaturas\busca_inscripcion.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tendras en la llamada [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) anterior a pedir [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-num-rows.php) de la ejecución de la SQL.

Antes de operar con el resultad de una llamada [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) has de verificar que la llamada sea correcta ya que mysql_query puede retornar el puntero de la ejecución de la consulta o un valor booleano **FALSE** cuando la consulta no se ha podido ejecutar por alguna razón. Como por ejemplo si el recurso de ejecución no existe por no estar declarada la variable (uso dentro de una función, otro espacio, conexión cerrada,...)  y tambien si la propia SQL es incorrecta.